# Windows Forms and ShowDialog problem

Tags: .net, winforms, showdialog

I have a borderless [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application.

The main window creates other forms (simple dialogs where I can click yes or no) with `ShowDialog()`.
Every created dialog is not visible in the taskbar, my application has only one taskbar entry that focuses my application (and if a dialog is open that one is focused). If I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle to all open windows I only see one entry, too.

However, if the dialog is created while my application doesn't have the focus (for example the user starts a long running task, starts to work on something else and while being in the background, my application shows a dialog "Task done...") and I want to go back to my application, things are getting strange.

- If I click on the taskbar to focus my application, the main window is focused (not the dialog).
- I can't use the main window (because there is still an open modal dialog).
- Windows 7 <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> preview shows the Dialog while the taskbar mouseover preview shows the main window (in normal behavior both show the dialog in front of the main window).
- The only way to make my application usable again is to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the entry and close the modal dialog.
- If I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> only the dialog is brought to the front and the main window is still in the background.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?
I know what to do, but most customers think the application crashed since the main window doesn't respond.

Update:

The solution is to pass the top level window to the `ShowDialog()` method (in most cases and if used in a form that would be the "this").

Since I didn't wanted to refactor my entire code, and all my forms inherit from "MyCustomFormBase" here is a little solution that works very well.

```
Public Class MyCustomFormBase

    Public Shared Property ApplicationMainForm() As Form
        Get
            Return _applicationMainform
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Form)
            _applicationMainform = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared _applicationMainform As Form

    Public Shadows Function ShowDialog() As DialogResult
        If MyCustomFormBase.ApplicationMainForm IsNot Nothing Then
            Return MyBase.ShowDialog(MyCustomFormBase.ApplicationMainForm)
        Else
            Return MyBase.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shadows Function ShowDialog(ByVal owner As IWin32Window) As DialogResult
        Return MyBase.ShowDialog(owner)
    End Function

End Class
```

In the constructor of the main window I use

```
MyCustomFormBase.ApplicationMainForm = Me
```

once. It helped me half a day refactoring ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried passing a reference to the main window to `ShowDialog` calls?

```
// assuming this code is in the main form (so "this" refers to the main form)
DialogForm dialog = new DialogForm();
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

Quote from the [documentation of this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx):

> This version of the ShowDialog method
>   allows you to specify a specific form
>   or control that will own the dialog
>   box that is shown. If you use the
>   version of this method that has no
>   parameters, the dialog box being shown
>   would be owned automatically by the
>   currently active window of your
>   application.

Comment: I propably used the method a thousand times and never noticed that there is an overload ;) Anyway that works. thx a lot.

Comment: +1, without the argument it will try to find one.  The desktop window, if necessary.