# ShowDialog(owner) is hiding behind/not showing even though I am supplying owner IWin32Window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, view, krypton-toolkit

Please do not close the question straight away. The almost similar problem is also discussed in the following threads.

1. [Windows Forms and ShowDialog problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2922940/530767)
2. [Form.ShowDialog() or Form.ShowDialog(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816885/530767)

But, these do not solve my problem.
The problem never occurred in my development machine. It occurred in the user machine but not always. In fact it occurred only 3 or 4 times.

When it happens it seems the application/calling form is frozen. If I can guess (as I am not seeing it on the screen) where the close button is and click on it on the called form, it closes and application goes back to usable state until it occurs again.

My views are encapsulated within the presenter, so I am not calling `ShowDialog()` from within the view but through the presenter.

```
MainPresenter
{
    MainPresenter(IMainView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }
    …
    …
    OpenSecondView()
    {
        var secondPresenter =_presenterFactory.Create<SecondPresenter>();
        secondPresenter.Ininialize(_view);
    }
}

// Initialize method in the SecondPresenter
Initialize(owner)
{
    _secondView.ShowDialog(owner); 
}
```

I am using observing presenter style of MVP explained here
http://www.aspiringcraftsman.com/2008/11/23/model-view-presenter-styles/

**Questions:**

1. How can I reproduce the problem in my development machine and fix it?
2. If I use `Show()` and set `TopMost = true`, is it possible this problem
   to occur?
3. **What are the things I should consider that may cause this problem?**

If `Show()` absolutely guarantees that the problem will not occur, I will go with `Show()`. I kind of lost faith in `ShowDialog()` on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

** The problem does not occur for a specific screen/view. It occurs randomly.

** For all the forms except main form, ShowInTaskBar is set to false.

Comment: Your code snippet is useless to diagnose this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree, i posted them here to show how i am calling the view, if that matters.

Comment: @HansPassant If you are interested to see any particular code, I can post here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `this.Activate()` in the load event for the form, because I have had a similar problem.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about why should i need to call this.Active()?

Comment: I have seen dialogs popup but behind the current form which means having to alt-tab to get the dialog.  Is this the problem that you are refering to?  Did you find a solution as it has been some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `TopMost = true` for the form